# Why is the toolbar not working in TinyMCE editor in popup?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I have a tinymce editor in my popup, but can't use toolbar (File, Edit, Format etc), they are not visible for me because I am in popup.

Example code:

```
   $('#popupdId").arcticmodal({
    overlay: {
        css: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.6
        }
    },
    afterClose:function () {
        showBodyYScroll();
    }
});

     tinymce.init({
    selector: '#testId",
    plugins: "link",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
            this.setContent('');
        });
    }
});
```

Example of my tinymce:
https://clip2net.com/s/3ZFngUM

Maybe there are some correct methods for adding tinymce into a popup, like append or other?

Answer (score 0):

The Menubar (the area with File, Edit, etc) certainly looks visible in your screenshot.  I suspect what you mean is that they are disabled (e.g. you cannot actually click on them)?

Some modal environments want to take away the ability for any other element on the screen to grab focus.  For example in Bootstrap you would do something like this:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

No idea what you are using for modals but that could be an issue.

I would also look at CSS to see if you have some CSS that is impacting the menubar.

Ideally you would make a JS Fiddle or CodePen showing this issue in action so people can see exactly how you have things setup.